# Select all but the first character in a string

Tags: mysql, substring

How can you return a string minus the first character in a string in MySQL?

In other words, get 'ello' from 'hello'.

The only way I can think to do it is to use mid() with the second offset being larger than the string could possibly be:

```
select mid('hello', 2, 99)
```

But I'm convinced there must be a more elegant way of doing it. Is there?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use [`SUBSTR`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substr) (or `SUBSTRING`):

```
SELECT SUBSTR( 'hello', 2 );
--> 'ello'
```

*See also: [MySQL String Functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html)*

Answer (score 2):

That is actually incorrect.  If you do that, you only get llo.  In order to get
everything after the first character....do the following:

```
<?php
echo substr('hello', 1); // Output ello
echo '<br />';
echo substr('hello', 2); // Output llo
?>
```

I just wanted to correct that.

Edit: Bah, ignore me. I thought you were talking about in PHP.  Well anyway, you can do that in
Mysql..or you can just get it in PHP as I posted above.

Answer (score 0):

what about select substr('hello', 2)?